# Empty password when retrieving users from UserFeed with Google Apps API

Tags: .net, google-apps, google-provisioning-api

I am trying to retrieve all user accounts in my domain using Google apps api with .net!

But the problem is: the UserEntry.Login.Password is alway empty.

Is it possible to retrieve users with their password using the api?
If not, is there a solution to login into the user's Gmail using domain admin password?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. User passwords are not returned by the API. An Administrator can update the user password but cannot retrieve it.

For reference, see:
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/reference#google_apps_tag_apps:login

Comment: Thank you Jay ! So if I want to log into a user account I have to set the password to a that one I know ?? And there is no other solution to impersonate the user ?